# Schema Compare and Deployment Scripts

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project

I have a VS2012 database project and am using schema compare to release from the development to the live database.

I had assumed that the pre-deployment and post-deployment scripts would be executed before and after the schema compare update script.  But it seems these scripts are never executed as part of a schema compare.

Is this by design or is there a setting somewhere I have missed?

[image: Build Menu]

Answer (score 4):

When you are comparing schemas you are not actually deploying the database, so the pre- and post-deployment scripts won't run.

You have to select Deploy from Build menu for this scripts to run.

Comment: I'm sure you are right, but I am confused.   On the build menu there is the option to deploy the solution, but not to deploy the database project.   I thougt the schema compare tool was what people were using to move changes from dev to live?

Comment: When you select your database project root in Solution Explorer window you will have option to deploy this project in Build menu. In our organisation we don't use deploy function in database projects, we use schema compare to generate migration scripts, because in our opinion this tool is much more convienient than deploy.

Comment: I have edited the original question to show the build menu.  I get the option to deploy the solution or to publish the database.  Do you mean to use publish the database?  @Jojo - I agree schema compare is a convenient tool - thats what I'm confused about, it seems to do everything I want except populate lookup tables with required data

Comment: Use the "Publish" option to generate the script. You have the option to either generate a script or publish the changes directly. Generating the script will do what you want. You can even automated the generation of the script using SQLPackage if you prefer to automate in that manner.